# Returning a generic List java

Tags: java, list, generics

I'm trying to create a method to return a list of generic objects but I'm getting a ClassCastException.

```
HashMap<String, String> dados = new HashMap<>();
List<HashMap<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<>();

dados.put("sigla", "TST");
dados.put("nome", "Teste");
result.add(dados);

List<Posto> dadosProcessados = convertDados(Posto.class, result);

for (Posto posto : dadosProcessados) { //ClassCastException line 38
    System.out.println(posto.getSigla() + " => " + posto.getNome());
}
```

and here is the complete method:

```
public static <T> List<T> convertDados(Class<T> entity, List<HashMap<String, String>> dados) throws NoSuchMethodException, 
SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
    Field[] fields = entity.getDeclaredFields();
    Method[] allSetterMethods = entity.getMethods();
    Map<Integer, Method> setters = new HashMap<>();
    Class<?>[] paramTypes = new Class<?>[fields.length -1];
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int cont  = 0;

    //Pega todos os setter
    for(Method method : allSetterMethods) {         
        if(method.getName().startsWith("set")) {
            paramTypes[cont] = method.getParameterTypes()[0];
            setters.put(cont, method);
            cont++;
        }
    }

    for (Field field : fields) {            
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> dado: dados.get(0).entrySet()) {
            if(dado.getValue() != null && field.getName().equals(dado.getKey())) {
                for(Map.Entry<Integer, Method> set : setters.entrySet()) {
                    if(set.getValue().getName().substring(3).equalsIgnoreCase(field.getName())) {
                        Method method = entity.getMethod(set.getValue().getName(), paramTypes[set.getKey()]);
                        method.invoke(entity.getConstructor().newInstance(), dado.getValue());
                        result.add((T) entity);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The Error stacktrace

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to data.bo.Posto at beans.Teste.main(Teste.java:38)

Comment: What's the error? Can you include the stacktrace?

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to data.bo.Posto
 at beans.Teste.main(Teste.java:38)`

Comment: What is on line 38 of Teste.java?

Comment: for (Posto posto : dadosProcessados). This is line 38

Comment: This line `result.add((T) entity);` makes no sense. Re-check what `entity` is and if it realy is what you like to add to the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change result.add((T)entity); with T obj = entity.getConstructor().newInstance();

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<HashMap<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<>();

    HashMap<String, String> dados = new HashMap<>();

    dados.put("sigla", "TST");
    dados.put("nome", "Teste");
    result.add(dados);

    List<Posto> dadosProcessados = convertDados(Posto.class, result);

    for (Posto posto : dadosProcessados) {
      System.out.println(posto.getSigla() + " => " + posto.getNome());
    }

  }


  public static <T> List<T> convertDados(Class<T> entity, List<HashMap<String, String>> dados) throws NoSuchMethodException,
      SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
    Field[] fields = entity.getDeclaredFields();
    Method[] allSetterMethods = entity.getMethods();
    Map<Integer, Method> setters = new HashMap<>();
    Class<?>[] paramTypes = new Class<?>[fields.length];
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int cont = 0;

    for (Method method : allSetterMethods) {
      if (method.getName().startsWith("set")) {
        paramTypes[cont] = method.getParameterTypes()[0];
        setters.put(cont, method);
        cont++;
      }
    }

    for (Field field : fields) {
      for (Map.Entry<String, String> dado : dados.get(0).entrySet()) {
        if (dado.getValue() != null && field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(dado.getKey())) {
          for (Map.Entry<Integer, Method> set : setters.entrySet()) {
            if (set.getValue().getName().substring(3).equalsIgnoreCase(field.getName())) {
              Method method = entity.getMethod(set.getValue().getName(), paramTypes[set.getKey()]);
              T obj = entity.getConstructor().newInstance();
              method.invoke(obj, dado.getValue());
              result.add(obj);
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `result.add((T) entity);` to the result.  Entity is the parameter you passed in, which is a class and not an instance of the type you intended.

Perhaps you meant to add the result of `entity.getConstructor().newInstance()` to the list instead?